# Will NEST 1.0 Work with Elastic Search 0.x?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Going over the blog posts and documentation, I couldn't get a clear answer: is NEST 1.0 backwards compatible with Elastic Search 0.x?

We compared the requests we use, and didn't find any caveats (yet), but a clear answer would be nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially **NO**

We only test the `1.x` releases of NEST with the `1.x` releases of Elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch itself has many breaking changes as part of its 1.0 release that `NEST 0.12` does not accomodate for:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking-changes.html

Having said if your request is untouched by Elastisearch own breaking changes you might get away with it but please know that we do not support using `NEST 0.12` against `Elasticsearch 1.x`